# Matrices with Arrows

Tags: matrices, arrows

Does anyone know how to deal with the vertical arrows?
The code I have so far is below:

[image]

```
\hspace{0.75cm}
$\xleftrightarrow{\text{\hspace{4.25cm}j \hspace{4.25cm}}}$
\newline
\updownarrow{\text{i}}
\newline
\updownarrow{\text{i}}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 & y_1 & ... & y_{j-1} \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
y_{i-2} & y_{i-1} & ... & y_{i+j-3} \\
y_{i-i} & y_{i} & ... & y_{i+j-2} \\
\noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt} & \noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt} & \noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt} & \noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt} \\
y_{i} & y_{i+1} & ... & y_{i+j-1} \\
y_{i+1} & y_{i+2} & ... & y_{i+j} \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
y_{2i-1} & y_{2i} & ... & y_{2i+j-2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

Answer (score 4):

This a possible way: mark the coordinates of some special points (e.g., corners of the matrix), and then use `tikz` to draw the arrows. You may want to compile a couple of times

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\pincoord}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}



\[
  Y_{0|2i-1} \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \quad\pincoord{A}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \pincoord{B}  y_0 & y_1 & ... & y_{j-1} \pincoord{C} \\
    ... & ... & ... & ... \\
    y_{i-2} & y_{i-1} & ... & y_{i+j-3} \\
     \pincoord{F} y_{i-i} & y_{i} & ... & y_{i+j-2} \pincoord{G} \\
    y_{i} & y_{i+1} & ... & y_{i+j-1} \\
    y_{i+1} & y_{i+2} & ... & y_{i+j} \\
    ... & ... & ... & ... \\
     \pincoord{D}  y_{2i-1}& y_{2i} & ... & y_{2i+j-2} \pincoord{E}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \pincoord{H} \qquad\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \left(\frac{Y_{0|i-1}}{Y_{i|2i-1}}\right)  \quad\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 
  \left(\frac{Y_p}{Y_f}\right)
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, >=stealth]
  \draw[<->] ([xshift = -1ex, yshift = 2pt]A) -- ([xshift = -1ex]A |- B) node[midway, left] {i};
  \draw[<->] ([xshift = -1ex, yshift =-2pt]A) -- ([xshift = -1ex]A |- D) node[midway, left] {i};
  \draw[<->] ([yshift = 3ex]B) -- ([yshift = 3ex]B -| C) node[midway, above] {J};
  \draw[] ([yshift = -5pt]F) -- ([yshift = -5pt]G);
  \draw[<->] ([xshift = 1ex, yshift = 2pt]H) -- ([xshift = 1ex]H |- B) node[midway, right] {``past''};
  \draw[<->] ([xshift = 1ex, yshift =-2pt]H) -- ([xshift = 1ex]H |- D) node[midway, right] {``future''};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect job for a `tikz matrix`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \[
    Y_{0\mid 2i-1} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, baseline=(mybaseline)]
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=),
    inner xsep=2pt,
    ] (mymatr) {%
    y_0 & y_1 & \cdots & y_{j-1} \\[-6pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    y_{i-2} & y_{i-1} & \cdots & y_{i+j-3} \\
    y_{i-1}% there was a little typo here 
    & y_{i} & \cdots & y_{i+j-2} \\[12pt]
    y_{i} & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{i+j-1} \\
    y_{i+1} & y_{i+2} & \cdots & y_{i+j} \\[-6pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    y_{2i-1} & y_{2i} & \cdots & y_{2i+j-2} \\
    };
\coordinate (mybaseline) at ([yshift=-9pt]mymatr-4-1.south west);
\coordinate (mystart) at ([yshift=-6pt]mymatr-4-1.south west);
\coordinate (mystop)  at ([yshift=-6pt]mymatr-4-4.south east);
\coordinate (myne)  at ([xshift=16pt]mymatr.north east);
\coordinate (myse)  at ([xshift=16pt]mymatr.south east);
\coordinate (mynw)  at ([xshift=-16pt]mymatr.north west);
\coordinate (mysw)  at ([xshift=-16pt]mymatr.south west);
\draw (mystart) -- (mystop);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway},
every path/.style={<->}]
\draw (myne) -- (myne |- mystop) node[right] {``past''};
\draw (myse) -- (myse |- mystop) node[right] {``future''};
\draw (mynw) -- (mynw |- mystop) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (mysw) -- (mysw |- mystop) node[left] {$i$};
\draw ([yshift=10pt]mymatr.north west) -- ([yshift=10pt]mymatr.north east) node[above] {$j$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-34pt}% <--- but I would omit this
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\biggl(\frac{Y_{0\mid i-1}}{Y_{i\mid 2i-1}}\biggr)
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\biggl(\frac{Y_{p}}{Y_{f}}\biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. This method works too! You guys are really awesome :)
Thank you :)

Comment: @Pravin You're welcome! Since you have some responses that answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \cmidrule

\begin{document}

\[ \NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}
Y_{0\mid 2i-1} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\begin{NiceArray}{cccccc}[baseline = line-6]
    & \Hdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},shorten = 0pt]{4}^{j} \\
  \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},shorten = 0pt]{4}_{\rotatebox{90}{$i$}} 
    & y_0 & y_1 & \cdots & y_{j-1} & 
        \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},shorten = 0pt]{4}^{\rotatebox{90}{``past''}} \\
    & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    & y_{i-2} & y_{i-1} & \cdots & y_{i+j-3} \\
    & y_{i-1} & y_{i} & \cdots & y_{i+j-2} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},shorten = 0pt]{4}_{\rotatebox{90}{$j$}} 
    & y_{i} & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{i+j-1} & 
        \Vdotsfor[line-style={solid,<->},shorten = 0pt]{4}^{\rotatebox{90}{``future''}} \\
    & y_{i+1} & y_{i+2} & \cdots & y_{i+j} \\
    & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    & y_{2i-1} & y_{2i} & \cdots & y_{2i+j-2} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-2}{9-5})
\end{NiceArray}
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\biggl(\frac{Y_{0\mid i-1}}{Y_{i\mid 2i-1}}\biggr)
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\biggl(\frac{Y_{p}}{Y_{f}}\biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]