# Adding Arrows that come through Numbers within Matrices

Tags: matrices, arrows

Here is a pic of what I need.

Need help for achieving this.
[image]

The Arrow pierced  numbers in rows and columns here.

```
\documentclass[8pt,letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage[left=8mm,top=6mm,bottom=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}   
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1\\
-2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 2\\ 
    1& 1 & 1\\
    2 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you not provide MWE? This matrix was used so far at least in three your question. It is not fun to retype it, especial knowing, that you already wrote it before. Help us to help you!

Comment: @Zarko what's "MWE"? Sorry for not providing MWE. Bro

Comment: MWE (Minimal working Example) is small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`  (based on your real document). In its preamble are loaded only necessary, to your problem relevant packages and preamble also contain your defined  defined commands, which are needed that it reproduce your problem or errors with which you are faced. Interestingly, building MWE many times solve your problem. With MWE the people who are willing to help you, are liberated to wrote your  code from scratch can can, what is the most important, more easy help you.

Comment: Many times happens, that question without MWE are down voted (as happen with your question) or it can be closed as *needs more details* or *needs more focus*. MWE also helps other members of this site, which has similar problems, to solve theirs problems.  Answers, which you get on your question(s) contains MWE. With them you can test proposed solutions and decide which is the most appropriate to you. It is expected, that you accept this answer and up vote (when you will earn rights) all others which gives you valuable suggestion.

Comment: Document class article has defined only 10 pt, 11 pt and 12 pt font sizes. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure.

Comment: This looks very like your earlier question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527044 .  Are they related or duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the extension `nicematrix` which creates Tikz nodes under each cell of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %nicematrix does not load tikz. Must load tikz for arrows.meta
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=A]
1 & 2 & -1 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
%
\hspace{1cm}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=B]
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 4 
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    [ remember picture, 
      overlay, 
      every path/.style = 
        { -Straight Barb ,
          color=red,
          very thick,
          semitransparent,
          shorten >=-1pt,
          shorten <=-1pt } ]
 \draw (A-1-1.west) -- (A-1-3.east) ;
 \draw (B-1-2.north) -- (B-3-2.south) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Can you improve your answer like what Zarko did here?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Vzt.png

Comment: @kile: I have modified my answer in order to obtain the same result as Zarko. :-)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

With use of the `tikzmark` library from `tikz` package. To get showed result you need to compile MWE at least twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}       

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmarknode{a1}{1} 
    &  2 & \tikzmarknode{a2}{-1}    \\
 -2 &  0 &  1   \\
  1 & -1 &  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & \tikzmarknode{b1}{1} 
        & 2     \\   
  1 & 1 & 1     \\    
  2 & \tikzmarknode{b2}{3} 
        & 4     \\   
\end{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, 
arr/.style = {draw=red, -Straight Barb, very thick, semitransparent,
              shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt}
                        ]
\draw[arr] (a1.west)  -- (a2.east);
\draw[arr] (b1.north) -- (b2.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied yours, it's not working.

Comment: Here is the messsage for this! ```! Package pgf Error: No shape named a1 is known.```

Comment: Proposed MWE is tested and it works (all shapes are well defined in it, see the code of matrices)! By it is generated showed math expression. I use the recent MikTeX installation. Try to update your LaTeX installation. if you use Overleaf service, than unfortunately you will not get the same result, since its LaTeX repository doesn't contain last version of `tikz` package with their libraries.

Comment: I use TeX Live here. `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode`

Comment: @kile, sorry, I'm not familiar with TeX Live, so I can't say, if your installation contain the last version of used packages and libraries. Check this with TeX Live utilities. If you need help in this, search first the site and in the case, that you not find anything helpful, ask new question, how to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to use `nicematrix` method to solve this?

Comment: @kile, the second answer use the `nicematrix` package! It is written by package author ... Do you check all gotten answers?

Comment: I've seen his work. But the result is not as perfect as yours.

Comment: Than ask the answer author that he improve it.

Answer (score 2):

A startup to point you in the right direction -- I think you will be able to take it from here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, baseline=(mybaseline)]
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=),
    inner xsep=2pt,
    ] (mymatr) {%
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    {i-2} & {i-1} & \cdots & {i+j-3} \\
    y_{i-1}% there was a little typo here 
    & y_{i} & \cdots & y_{i+j-2} \\[12pt]
    y_{i} & y_{i+1} & \cdots & y_{i+j-1} \\
    y_{i+1} & y_{i+2} & \cdots & y_{i+j} \\[-6pt]
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    y_{2i-1} & y_{2i} & \cdots & y_{2i+j-2} \\
    };
\coordinate (mybaseline) at ([yshift=-9pt]mymatr-4-1.south west);
\coordinate (mystart) at ([yshift=-6pt]mymatr-4-1.south west);
\coordinate (mystop)  at ([yshift=-6pt]mymatr-4-4.south east);
\coordinate (myne)  at ([xshift=16pt]mymatr.north east);
\coordinate (myse)  at ([xshift=16pt]mymatr.south east);
\coordinate (mynw)  at ([xshift=-16pt]mymatr.north west);
\coordinate (mysw)  at ([xshift=-16pt]mymatr.south west);
\draw (mystart) -- (mystop);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway},
every path/.style={->}]
\draw ([yshift=-10pt]mymatr.north west) -- ([yshift=-10pt]mymatr.north east) node[above] {$j$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Adapted from a solution provided by @CarLaTeX -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430681/197451