# TeX Live is having trouble translating this below

Tags: texlive

Here is the work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                tikzmark}       

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\tikzmarknode{a1}{1} 
    &  2 & \tikzmarknode{a2}{-1}    \\
 -2 &  0 &  1   \\
  1 & -1 &  0   \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & \tikzmarknode{b1}{1} 
        & 2     \\   
  1 & 1 & 1     \\    
  2 & \tikzmarknode{b2}{3} 
        & 4     \\   
\end{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, 
arr/.style = {draw=red, -Straight Barb, very thick, semitransparent,
              shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt}
                        ]
\draw[arr] (a1.west)  -- (a2.east);
\draw[arr] (b1.north) -- (b2.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

*This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode*

The message is like this: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named a1 is known.`

That's what I want[image]

Do any smarts know what's happening here?

> ! Package pgf Error: No shape named a1 is known.
>
> See the pgf package documentation for explanation. Type  H  
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.26 \draw[arr] (a1.west)
>                              -- (a2.east); ?

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.9.15)  5 FEB 2020 11:51
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"TeXLive error.tex"
(./TeXLive error.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 223.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 385.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 482.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 485.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 606.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box27
\strutbox@=\box28
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 729.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 730.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2844.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2845.
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z.sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.st
y
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.
sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfut
il-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks19
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen112
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen113

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfut
il-common-lists.tex))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfut
il-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box29

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrc
s.code.tex
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.te
x)
Package: pgfrcs 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
Package: pgf 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcor
e.sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks20
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics
.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.d
ef
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsy
s.sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfke
ys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfke
ysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen116
\pgf@y=\dimen117
\pgf@xa=\dimen118
\pgf@ya=\dimen119
\pgf@xb=\dimen120
\pgf@yb=\dimen121
\pgf@xc=\dimen122
\pgf@yc=\dimen123
\pgf@xd=\dimen124
\pgf@yd=\dimen125
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count100
\c@pgf@countb=\count101
\c@pgf@countc=\count102
\c@pgf@countd=\count103
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count104

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
syssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count105
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count106
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf
sysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cf
g
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
ore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.co
de.tex
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcal
c.code.tex
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathuti
l.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathpar
ser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen126
\pgfmath@count=\count107
\pgfmath@box=\box30
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.code.tex
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.basic.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.random.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.comparison.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.base.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.round.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.misc.code.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfun
ctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathflo
at.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count108
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.cod
e.tex)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen127
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen128
\pgf@picminy=\dimen129
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen130
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen131
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen132
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen133
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen134
\pgf@xx=\dimen135
\pgf@xy=\dimen136
\pgf@yx=\dimen137
\pgf@yy=\dimen138
\pgf@zx=\dimen139
\pgf@zy=\dimen140
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen141
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen142
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen143
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen144
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfpic=\box31
\pgf@hbox=\box32
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box33
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count109
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen145
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen146
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen147
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen148
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen149
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@max=\dimen150
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count110
\pgf@shadingcount=\count111
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box34
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
oretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfc
orerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodu
leshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box35
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodu
leplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgf
comp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen151
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen152
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgf
comp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.
sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys
.sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfke
ys.code.tex))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.co
de.tex))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffo
r.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.co
de.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen153
\pgffor@skip=\dimen154
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/t
ikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgfli
braryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count112
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen155
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen156
\tikz@lasty=\dimen157
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen158
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen159
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen160
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen161
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen162
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen163
\tikz@figbox=\box36
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box37
\tikz@tempbox=\box38
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box39
\tikztreelevel=\count113
\tikznumberofchildren=\count114
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count115
\tikz@fig@count=\count116

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodu
lematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count117
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count118
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count119
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count120

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/t
ikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgfli
braryarrows.meta.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfarrowinset=\dimen164
\pgfarrowlength=\dimen165
\pgfarrowwidth=\dimen166
\pgfarrowlinewidth=\dimen167
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzmark/tikzlibraryt
ikzmark.code.tex
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-09-08 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.t
ex
Package: expl3 2019-09-08 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count121
\l_tmpa_int=\count122
\l_tmpb_int=\count123
\g_tmpa_int=\count124
\g_tmpb_int=\count125
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count126
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count127
\c_log_iow=\count128
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count129
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count130
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count131
\l__iow_indent_int=\count132
\c_zero_dim=\dimen168
\c_max_dim=\dimen169
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen170
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen171
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen172
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen173
\c_zero_skip=\skip46
\c_max_skip=\skip47
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip48
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip49
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip50
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip51
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip11
\c_max_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip13
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip15
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip16
\l_keys_choice_int=\count133
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count134
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen174
\g__intarray_font_int=\count135
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count136
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count137
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count138
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count139
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count140
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count141
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count142
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count143
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count144
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count145
\g__fp_array_int=\count146
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count147
\l__sort_length_int=\count148
\l__sort_min_int=\count149
\l__sort_top_int=\count150
\l__sort_max_int=\count151
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count152
\l__sort_block_int=\count153
\l__sort_begin_int=\count154
\l__sort_end_int=\count155
\l__sort_A_int=\count156
\l__sort_B_int=\count157
\l__sort_C_int=\count158
\l__str_internal_int=\count159
\c__str_replacement_char_int=\count160
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count161
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count162
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count163
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count164
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count165
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count166
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count167
\l__regex_balance_int=\count168
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count169
\l__regex_mode_int=\count170
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count171
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count172
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count173
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count174
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count175
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count176
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count177
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count178
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count179
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count180
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count181
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count182
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count183
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count184
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count185
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count186
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count187
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count188
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count189
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count190
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count191
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count192
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count193
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count194
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count195
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count196
\l__regex_step_int=\count197
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count198
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count199
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count266
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count267
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count268
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count269
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count270
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count271
\c_empty_box=\box40
\l_tmpa_box=\box41
\l_tmpb_box=\box42
\g_tmpa_box=\box43
\g_tmpb_box=\box44
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen175
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen176
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen177
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen178
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen179
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen180
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen181
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen182
\l__box_internal_box=\box45
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box46
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen183
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen184
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen185
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen186
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen187
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen188
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen189
\c_empty_coffin=\box47
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box48
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box49
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box50
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box51
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box52
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box53
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen190
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen191
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen192
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen193
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen194
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen195
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen196
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box54
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box55
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box56
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box57
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen197
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen198
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen199
\g__char_data_ior=\read2
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count272
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count273
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-p
dfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count274
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box58
))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l
3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2019-05-28 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xpa
rse.sty
Package: xparse 2019-05-28 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count275
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count276
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count277
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count278
)
\l__sn_x_dim=\dimen256
\l__sn_y_dim=\dimen257
\l__sn_xa_dim=\dimen258
\l__sn_ya_dim=\dimen259
)
No file "TeXLive error".aux.
\openout1 = `"TeXLive error.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.
mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count279
\scratchdimen=\dimen260
\scratchbox=\box59
\nofMPsegments=\count280
\nofMParguments=\count281
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count282
\MPscratchDim=\dimen261
\MPnumerator=\count283
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count284
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-bas
e.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.
sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefineke
ys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.st
y
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.st
y
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.
sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.s
ty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.s
ty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
(e:/Program Files (x86)/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds
.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(
```

Comment: If you compile it multiple times then it gives you what you want.

Comment: I have an updated TeXLive 2019 installation and fail to reproduce the error. One conceivable reason for the error is that you have an invisible character in either `\tikzmarknode{a1}{1} ` or `\draw[arr] (a1.west)  -- (a2.east);`. To exclude this you may test the code on your machine with e.g. https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/. The above code does not have the problem. Another possible reason could be that you manually installed packages. Finally, if nothing helps you could try the `nicematrix` package, but of course the better way to go is to fix whatever is causing this.

Comment: You could also show us your log file such that we can exclude possible reasons why this happens. (BTW, the error message *should* be `! Package pgf Error: No shape named \`a1' is known.` Do you get the very error message shown in your post?)

Comment: You could try to update your TeXLive installation. We are now at version `3.1.5b`.

Comment: check your installation. the code is good.

Comment: @hkh how can I update my installation?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  how can I update installation? Remove the old one and download a new version?

Comment: On a Mac, there is a `TeX Live Utility` with which you can `Refresh the package list` and `Update all packages`. I am assuming that this is similar under Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solve this by updating all. I find there is not a lot info on how to update TeX Live on a Windows machine. So I'd like to give more details here.**

1. Find the `tl-tray-menu.exe`. If you don't custom-install TeXLive, it's usually located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\texlive\2019`
2. Right click the icon on the right corner, choose `Package Manager`

[image]

3. Open `Repositories`, then select a mirror that is nearest to you. click `Save and Load`

[image]

4. Then double click `Update All`. In my case, `Update All` is gray as I've already updated it.

[image]

5. It will pop up a cmd window, just type `tlmgr update --all` there. Finally Press `Enter` button on your keyboard.

[image]

6. Okay. Be patient to wait! The waiting time depends on how many packages you need to update and how fast your internet is.

Comment: I'm glad that you sorted out how to update your TeX Live installation. +1!